# unable to make out how ~ operator works in c

Tags: c, expression, casting

I have this piece of code can you explain me the output

```
unsigned int x=3;
~x;
printf("%d",x);
```

output is 10
I am not able to make it how.

I have compiled the code on turbo c

Comment: Did you really write code/compile and run it, and it is giving you 10? Or did you just read this somewhere?

Comment: That code sample doesn't look as though it will compile. There's a missing semicolon after the `~x`.

Comment: That code will print `3`: http://ideone.com/S9Ht6DfT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as you've posted it won't compile. It will compile if you change `~x` to `x = ~x;`, but then it won't give the output "10".

The `~` operator creates a bitwise inverse of the number given. In binary, the number 3 as an eight-bit integer is represented by the bits `00000011`. The `~` operator will replace every one of those bits with its opposite, giving `11111100`, which is 252 unsigned, or -4 signed.

You declared `x` as an `unsigned int`, which means a 32-bit unsigned value on most platforms. So your original value is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011`, and the inverse is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111100`, or 4294967292.

Comment: @Mark: no, when JS Bangs wrote his answer there was a missing ; (see edits in question) so the code *wouldn't* compile.

Answer (score 2):

To print out unsigned values, *especially when manipulating bits*, use the unsigned format for `printf`:

```
printf("%u", x);
```

I'm not sure you've actually run the code you show. See this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 3;
    unsigned int y = ~x;

    printf("Decimal. x=%u y=%u\n", x, y);
    printf("Hex. 0x%08X y=0x%08X\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Decimal. x=3 y=4294967292
Hex. 0x00000003 y=0xFFFFFFFC
```

Why the values are as they are should be obvious by basic binary arithmetic (and keeping in mind that C's `~` operator flips the bits of its argument).